# SmsManager.sendTextMessage causing UI to freeze. Is there anything I can do about this?

Tags: android, sms, freeze

When pressing the send text message button, this method cause my app to freeze for about 1 second. I have been thinking about this issue for a while, and the only solution I could come up with is showing a progress spinner during freeze time, but that would probably annoy the user. Is there any trick that I can use? or please show me the right direction. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Send the SMS in different thread, or send it in an AsyncTask.

Comment: I tried sending in `doInBackground` of AsyncTask, but the UI was still frozen for a short amount of time. I think `SmsManager.sendTextMessage` may run on UI thread?